# Problem with grid system in bootstrap 5.3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hi I try design my front end of website with bootstrap 5.3, But I have Problem with the grid system. Because the classes is not work as they should do.

here this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12  bg-danger">

        </div>
        <div class="col-7 col-sm-8  bg-secondary"></div>
        <div class="col-2 col-sm-4 bg-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code excused in my screen (15.6 inch) as like screenshot blow:
[image]

and in small screen is like this:
[image]

as you can see the "col3", "col-7" and "col-2" is run in small screen and the "col-sm-12", "col-sm-8" and "col-sm-4" is work on another size of screen. But I think it should be the opposite. why this happened and how can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base on bootstrap documention col-sm start from 576px.

[image]

Comment: ok but the style for sm base on first screen shot is active in width over 1000 pixel. why this happened?

Comment: It's right because you didn't set col-md or col-lg, bootstrap uses min-width for media queries. so for screens above 576px col-sm styles will appeare. 
@sadegh